# A force of 10 lb is required to hold a spring stretched 4 in. beyond its natural length. (used hooke's law this time)

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

A force of 10 lb is required to hold a spring stretched 4 in.
beyond its natural length. How much work is done in stretching
it from its natural length to 6 in. beyond its natural length?

ok i used hooks law

$$  4 in = \frac 13 ft, 6 in = \frac 12 ft  $$ Edit^

$$f(x) = kx, k = \frac{10lb}{\frac 13ft}$$

so $$\int_{\frac 13}^{\frac 12} (30x)dx$$

$$\frac{30x^2}{2} = 15x^2$$

From $\frac 13$ to $\frac 12$ which = $\frac{25}{12}$ ft-lb...... but the book says $\frac{15}{4}$ ft-lb!!!!

Comment: someone please help me my test is in 2 days :(

Comment: hooold on i just found the section on hooks law...

Comment: ok its still off by a little i triple checked it wtf >.<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asked to calculate the work for stretching it *from its natural length* to 6 inches, so $W = \int_0^{1/2} 30x \, dx$.

Comment: ohhHHhhHhHhHhh my problem was the book used 10 as natural and 15 as d in the example then asked to integrate from 15 to 18 without saying 15 was its natural length :|

Comment: nevermind thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the natural length to solve this problem.

$10$ lb force required to stretch spring $4$ inches:

$10= k(4)$ so $k=10/4$

$\int_0^6 10/4x dx$

find the antiderivative:

$(5/4) x^2$ from $0$ to $6$.

plug in $6$, you get $45$ in-lbs. convert to ft-lbs by dividing by $12$. then you get $15/4$, the book's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the integral from $0$ to $\frac1{2}$. This is because you used $\frac1{3}$ for $x$.